# How to sort keys of a dictionnary posted in url?

Tags: python, django

I have this dict posted in `request.POST`:

```
<QueryDict: {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'fhvpUorGAl7LMv4JIJRd0WOEHPkKn6iN'], u'actor_1': [u'first_actor'], u'actor_5': [u'second_actor'], u'actor_55': [u'third_actor'], u'actor_2': [u'fourth_actor']}>
```

i want to sort it by the keys to have

```
<QueryDict: {u'actor_1': [u'first_actor'], u'actor_2': [u'fourth_actor'], u'actor_5': [u'second_actor'], u'actor_55': [u'third_actor'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'fhvpUorGAl7LMv4JIJRd0WOEHPkKn6iN']}>
```

Is there a way to sort keys (not values) of a dictionnary ?

Comment: @tea2code that is sorting a dictionary by the values, not the keys?  So not quite the same question as far as I can see

Comment: I copied the wrong link sorry. The correct one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/python-dictionary-sort-by-key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Common dicts are, as mentioned, unordered by nature, but you can use OrderedDicts.

```
import collections

d = {
    u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'fhvpUorGAl7LMv4JIJRd0WOEHPkKn6iN'], 
    u'actor_1': [u'first_actor'], 
    u'actor_2': [u'fourth_actor']
}

collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d.items()))
```

Comment: The simple way is listed in the seconde link given by tea2code:
`req_posts = request.POST`
`sorted_posts = sorted(req_posts.iterkeys())`

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries cannot be sorted. Instead use for example a list.

However you can print out the values sorted by using:

```
d = {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'fhvpUorGAl7LMv4JIJRd0WOEHPkKn6iN'], 
 u'actor_1'            : [u'first_actor'], 
 u'actor_5'            : [u'second_actor'], 
 u'actor_55'           : [u'third_actor'], 
 u'actor_2'            : [u'fourth_actor']}

keys = d.keys()
keys.sort()
for key in keys:
   print d[key]

print keys
```

Result:

```
[u'first_actor']
[u'fourth_actor']
[u'second_actor']
[u'third_actor']
[u'fhvpUorGAl7LMv4JIJRd0WOEHPkKn6iN']
[u'actor_1', u'actor_2', u'actor_5', u'actor_55', u'csrfmiddlewaretoken']
```

Which displays all sorted values and last line displaying the sorted keys.

Answer (score 0):

No. Fundamentally, the keys in a Python dictionary are unordered. check the dictionary documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Comment: No ! they are, see tea2code's link in comment :)

Comment: @Drwhite **in** a `dict`ionary keys are **not** sorted(i.e. the order in which they are displayed when printing, or yielded when iterating is pseudo-random). tea2code shows a *different* data structure, which does *not* "sort" the keys. It simply keeps track of the order in which the keys were *added* (not their alphabetical order!)